# AF_INET socket when only IPv6 addresses are available on system?

Tags: c++, c, ipv6

Can you open `AF_INET` socket when only IPv6 addresses are available on system?

I'm trying to get the HWADDR for one system that may have only IPv6 addresses active (not dual stack).

Will I be able to open a socket using `AF_INET`? I'm only interested in finding the MAC address

Comment: Can't you use `SIOCGIFHWADDR` on an `AF_INET6` socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see the problem. You can call `SIOCGIFHWADDR` on both IPv4 and IPv6 sockets.

No matter if I use `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6` to create the socket, the `ioctl()` call succeeds and gives me the HW addr of the device I ask for.

Answer (score 1):

You surely could create an IPv4 socket using the system call `socket()`. However binding it to an IPv6 interface using `bind()` would fail.

Comment: I only need it to get the HW address using ioctl (SIOCGIFHWADDR flag)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IPv4 socket. If you could not, the system would also not be able to accept an IPv4 address when you connect to a v4-able network next month, see?

But I'm not sure SIOCGIFHWADDR will work without routes through a non-loopback interface. You could try tat on your target systems, or just try both AF_INET and AF_INET6, catch the error(s) and use whatever returns a result.